# Unexpected error from sparse.spdiags()

Tags: python, scipy, octave, sparse-matrix, diagonal

In Python 3 I am trying to run the following line of code to get a particular sparse matrix.

`sparse.spdiags(np.concatenate((-np.ones((9,1)), np.ones((9,1))), axis=1), [0, 1], 9, 10)`

This gives the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py", line 61, in spdiags
    return dia_matrix((data, diags), shape=(m,n)).asformat(format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/dia.py", line 138, in __init__
    % (self.data.shape[0], len(self.offsets)))
ValueError: number of diagonals (9) does not match the number of offsets (2)
```

Running what I understand to be the equivalent code in Octave seems to get me a sparse matrix.

```
spdiags([-ones(9,1) ones(9,1)],[0 1],9,10)

Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 9, cols = 10, nnz = 18 [20%])

(1, 1) -> -1
(1, 2) ->  1
(2, 2) -> -1
(2, 3) ->  1
(3, 3) -> -1
(3, 4) ->  1
(4, 4) -> -1
(4, 5) ->  1
(5, 5) -> -1
(5, 6) ->  1
(6, 6) -> -1
(6, 7) ->  1
(7, 7) -> -1
(7, 8) ->  1
(8, 8) -> -1
(8, 9) ->  1
(9, 9) -> -1
(9, 10) ->  1
```

Any ideas on why they are behaving differently, and how to fix it?

**ADDITION**

I'm having an additional problem with Scipy.sparse's output vs Octave's.

PYTHON

```
>>> sparse.spdiags(np.concatenate((-np.ones((9,1)),np.ones((9,1))), axis=1).T, [0,1],9,10).A
array([[-1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.]])

>>> sparse.spdiags(np.concatenate((-np.ones((9,1)),np.ones((9,1))), axis=1).T, [0,1],9,10).A.shape                                                      
(9, 10)

>>> sparse.spdiags(np.vstack([-np.ones(9),np.ones(9)]), [0,1],9,10).A                         
array([[-1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.]])

>>> sparse.spdiags(np.vstack([-np.ones(9),np.ones(9)]), [0,1],9,10).A.shape
(9, 10) 

>>> sparse.spdiags(np.ones(9)*[[-1],[1]], [0,1],9,10).A
array([[-1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.]])

>>> sparse.spdiags(np.ones(9)*[[-1],[1]], [0,1],9,10).A.shape
(9, 10)
```

OCTAVE

```
>full(spdiags([-ones(9,1) ones(9,1)],[0 1],9,10))
ans =

  -1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0  -1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0  -1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0  -1   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0  -1   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0  -1   1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   1   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   1

>size(full(spdiags([-ones(9,1) ones(9,1)],[0 1],9,10)))
ans =

9   10
```

Why does scipy and Octave not give the same value at the last column of the last row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `concatenate` produces a (9,2) matrix:

```
In [310]: np.concatenate((-np.ones((9,1)), np.ones((9,1))), axis=1)
Out[310]: 
array([[-1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1.]])

In [311]: _.shape
Out[311]: (9, 2)
```

`spdiags` doc describes this `data` parameter as `matrix diagonals stored row-wise`.  That is, each row of the matrix corresponds to a diagonal.  9 rows, but only 2 values in `[0,1]`.

This is an important difference, that I alluded to in my previous answer, though maybe I didn't stress it enough.

If you want 2 diagonals, you need give it a `(2,9)` array, such as the transpose of this matrix:

```
In [317]: sparse.spdiags(np.concatenate((-np.ones((9,1)),
    np.ones((9,1))), axis=1).T, [0,1],9,10)
Out[317]: 
<9x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 18 stored elements (2 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
```

You could also construct the diagonals with:

```
In [321]: np.concatenate([-np.ones((1,9)), np.ones((1,9))],axis=0)
Out[321]: 
array([[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Or `np.vstack([-np.ones(9),np.ones(9)])` or `np.ones(9)*[[-1],[1]]`.

---

Look at my previous answer, but change the final shape, to make more columns than rows):

```
octave:17> reshape (1:12, 4, 3)
ans =
    1    5    9
    2    6   10
    3    7   11
    4    8   12

octave:18> full(spdiags (reshape (1:12, 4, 3), [-1 0 1], 4,5))
ans =
    5    9    0    0    0
    1    6   10    0    0
    0    2    7   11    0
    0    0    3    8   12

In [327]: np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,4)
Out[327]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])

In [328]: sparse.spdiags(np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,4), [-1, 0, 1], 4,5).A
Out[328]: 
array([[ 5, 10,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  6, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  7, 12,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  3,  8,  0]])
```

In Octave (and presumably MATLAB) the +1 diagonal starts with 9, ends with 12, the full last column from the input matrix.  Look at [2,6,10] - in a right angle arrangment.

The scipy diagonal starts with 10, ends with an added 0.  The `9` is invisible in the nonexistent row above.  Look at [2,6,10] - in one column.

They are both consistent - in their own way.  So at least when there are more columns than rows, you'll need to take the difference into account when creating the input matrix.

Another `scipy` function takes the ambiguity out, by expecting the correct number of elements for each diagonal (as a list of lists):

```
In [337]: sparse.diags([[1,2,3],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]],[-1,0,1],(4,5),dtype=int).A
Out[337]: 
array([[ 5,  9,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  6, 10,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  7, 11,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  3,  8, 12]])
```

Note that I had to omit the `4`.

Look at the `tocoo` method in `scipy/sparse/dia.py` to see more about how a `dia_matrix` maps the diagonals data on to the sparse coordinates (`coo` format).